# I am using webview_flutter to show html content in mobile in emulator and in debug mode it is working but when i released the apk is not working

Tags: android, flutter, webview-flutter

`it is showing the black screen when the html page is`

`I/flutter (16317): #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure>`
`framework.dart:4334`
`I/flutter (16317): #1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup`
`framework.dart:4348`
`I/flutter (16317): #2      Element.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`
`framework.dart:4368`
`I/flutter (16317): #3      MediaQuery.maybeOf`
`media_query.dart:925`
`I/flutter (16317): #4      _InkResponseState._shouldShowFocus`
`ink_well.dart:1021`
`I/flutter (16317): #5      _InkResponseState.updateFocusHighlights`
`ink_well.dart:1037`
`I/flutter (16317): #6      _InkResponseState.handleFocusHighlightModeChange.<anonymous closure>`
`ink_well.dart:1016`
`I/flutter (16317): #7      State.setState`
`framework.dart:1133`
`I/flutter (16317): #8      _InkResponseState.handleFocusHighlightModeChange`
`ink_well.dart:1015`
`I/flutter (16317): #9      FocusManager.`*`notifyHighlightModeListeners (package:flutter/src/widgets/focus`*
`I/flutter (16317):`

the code is related to something which i don't know ,the code is related to something which i don't know,the code is related to something which i don't know,the code is related to something which i don't know,the code is related to something which i don't know,the code is related to something which i don't know,.the code is related to something which i don't know,the code is related to something which i don't know,

Comment: Did you give the internet permissions in Android manifest file? Manifest file present in the path: "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"

Comment: yes i give the internet permission